# Moving average across two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let's say I want to do a 10 line moving average over multiple columns. To simplify, I made this visual example:
[image: EXAMPLE]

I want to enter the algo into cell C12 and fill down. It should take a 10 line average, starting with column 1. As column 1 ends, or has blanks, more of the 10 will be taken from column 2, until it is only column 2.

C12 should equate to:
=(sum(A3:A11)+B12)/10

C13 should equate to:
=(sum(A4:A11)+sum(B12:13))/10

C14 should equate to:
=(sum(A5:A11)+sum(B12:14))/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try harder to figure it out myself. The following works well:

=IF(COUNT(B$12:B12)>=10,AVERAGE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-9,COLUMN(B12))):B12),(SUM(A3:A$11)+SUM(B$12:B12))/10)

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Start with

```
=(sum(A3:A$11)+sum(B$12:B12))/10
```

Copy down. Screenshot uses `=formulatext(G4)` copied down to show formulas

[image]

**Edit**

If there is only ever one number between columns A and B, then your formula can be a lot simpler. In C12 you can use

```
=Sum(A3:B12)/10
```

Copy down.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I think this does not work. Eventually I would have way more than 10 numbers added together in "Column 2". For example

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately this does not work. Eventually I would have way more than 10 numbers added together. For example, when we eventually have all the numbers in column 2, then dollar sign on B$12 would have to be removed to maintain 10 numbers. I don't want to always do this manually.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: No, sorry, this is just a simplification, so that won't work. The reality is more complicated. The other column is in another sheet and contains a lot more data, and I have to do this many times. So, it needs to start on one column and end on the other, and eventually switch, not just do both columns at once.

Comment: in that case, you had better come up with a data sample that reflects your real world scenario better.